# How does one create optional command line arguments in oozie workflow xml

Tags: oozie, oozie-coordinator

Please bear in mind that I'm a complete rookie with oozie. I know that one can specify command line arguments in the oozie workflow xml by using the arg tag. I wondered how it is possible to specify an optional command line argument such that oozie will not complain that a required parameter is missing if the user doesn't specify it?

Many thanks in advance. If the information I've given is not specific enough, I can provide a concrete example when I log into my work machine tomorrow. We use apache commons CLI options to parse the options.

E.g. I want to make the following argument optional:

-e${endDateTime}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In theory you should be able to use a "config-default.xml" file next to your "workflow.xml" file to give default values to the params in the workflow (see https://oozie.apache.org/docs/3.2.0-incubating/WorkflowFunctionalSpec.html) but I couldn't get it working.

Comment: I found the following workaround. In the job.properties file write 'endDateTime=""', then in the java code, check for the existence of '""' and overwrite it with a default end date time. If you add the command line argument, that also overwrites whats in the job.properties file.

Answer (score 7):

In your workflow wherever you would use `${myparam}`, replace it with `${firstNotNull(wf:conf('myparam'), 'mydefaultvalue')}`